# Netbeans: Wrapping code around a word in HTML?

Tags: html, netbeans

If I'm in Netbeans and I want to wrap a `div` tag around the sentence `"hello world"`, I know I can start typing a `div` on the left side then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to finish the `div` tag on the left side of the sentence.  However, is there a shortcut such that I can finish the `div` on both sides of the sentence `<div> "hello world" </div>` without having to first write it on the left side, then click on the right side and write `</div>?`

Comment: Problem solved: highlight a word or sentence, then press alt + enter and select Surround with Tag option :)

Comment: Shortcut works. Ok. But Default value to "Surround with Tag" is DIV. Can I change it ?

Answer (score 6):

I didn't find any tag wrap option in netbeans but discovered an alternative. Install emmet plugin and use wrap with abbreviation from Edit>Emmet>Wrap with Abbreviation. For details check the following link...

https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/

Answer (score 0):

The default tag offered is DIV but if you type an alternative such as P it replaces the tags at both ends of the selected text.